# 高階関数とコールバック関数とは？

Tags: javascript

高階関数とは下記のPosition(Math.random());のように、関数の引数に関数を使った場合、
引数の関数を一般の関数と区別するために高階関数というのでしょうか？

```
let Position = (mathRandom) => {
    targetItem.style.top = (mathRandom * 100) + '%';
};

let setClickItem1 = setInterval(() => {
    Position(Math.random());
}, speed);
```

またコールバック関数とこんがらがるのですが、こちらは引数に使った関数はコールバック関数なのではなく関数に渡される関数のことをコールバック関数というのでしょうか？
違いが微妙です。

Comment: 一応の指摘ですが、質問中のコード`Position(Math.random());`は「関数の引数に関数を使った場合」になっていません。
`Math.random()`ですから、関数の実行結果の値を引数として渡しています。高階関数になっているのは `setInterval` の方ですね。
（質問者さんは応用的・発展的な内容から、いわば「降りていく」形で、基礎を含めた全てを理解しようとなさっているように思います。
これは成功の見込みが低いです。
以前も申し上げたかもしれず恐縮ですが、もっとも基礎的な所から積み上げる形で学習されるのがお勧めです）

Answer (score 3):

高階関数とは関数を引数として与えたり返したりできる関数のことです。
つまり関数を扱える関数のことです。
引数の関数（それもまた高階関数であるかもしれませんが）のことではありません。

コールバック関数とは渡される関数の目的からそのように呼ばれます。
例えば、
サーバーからデータを要求しその受け取ったデータで画面描画するとします。

```
data = loaddata();
draw(data);
```

このようにすると、
いつ終わるかわからない`loaddata()`の終了を待たなければなりません。
そこで、

```
loaddata(draw);
```

のように関数を渡して置いて
    読込が終了した時点で`loaddata`自体に`draw(data);`を実行してもらうようにします。

言わば、電話番号を渡しておいて仕事が終わったら電話してね、そしたら私はそれから私の仕事をするよ。
という感じです。
多分、こういうことを称してコールバックと言っていると思います。

別の例として
２つの引数をとり足し算をする関数`add`と
２つの引数をとり引き算をする関数`sub`が
あって、
２つの引数と渡された関数を適用して計算をする`calc`が
`calc(x, y, add);` のように呼び出される場合
`calc`のやることは`add(x,y)`のような呼び出しですが、
このような場合は`add`はコールバック関数とは呼ばれない（と思います）。

なので、渡す関数の目的によってそのように呼ばれるということになります。

Comment: 高階関数は
引数にある関数の事ではないのですね。

難しくて初心者には厳しいですね。

Comment: 普通は関数は文字列だったり数値だったりを扱いますが、その関数自体を扱うのでメタな関数であるというような意味ですね。

Comment: 関数自体を引数として使える関数のことを高階関数というのでしょうか？

Comment: そうです。そういう認識でいいと思います。

Comment: 普通の関数は引数に文字列だったり数値を入れるが、高階関数だけは引数に別の関数を入れる。
その様な関数を高階関数となずけた。
高階関数かどうかは関数で決まっているのでしょうか？

Comment: loaddata(draw);のloaddata関数ではなく、こちらに渡されるdraw関数の方がコールバック関数とというのですね。
高階関数は引数の方ではないので、真逆といった感じでしょうか？
始めの関数が終わったら引数の関数を実行してという引数に来る関数のことをコールバック関数とというという事でしょうか？

Comment: 「高階関数かどうかは関数で決まっているのでしょうか？」質問をちゃんと理解してないかもしれませんが、単にネーミングの問題だと思います。javascriptでは関数を高階関数として書けるので、javascriptにおける「関数」は高階関数たり得るという意味でそれぞれの関数自体に違いはありません。だから、その「関数が関数を扱える」ということを言っているに過ぎません。

Comment: 「始めの関数が終わったら引数の関数を実行してという引数に来る関数のことをコールバック関数とというという事でしょうか？」そうですね。そのように不定期に実行されることを目的としているかどうかで区別していると言っていいと思います。

Comment: ＞＞＞
「始めの関数が終わったら引数の関数を実行してという引数に来る関数のことをコールバック関数とというという事でしょうか？」そ‌​うですね。そのように不定期に実行されるこ‌​とを目的としているかどうかで区別している‌​と言っていいと思います。


順番通りに普通の処理される関数ではなく引数に記載することで、引数の大本の関数が実行された後に実行される関数のことをコールバック関数というのですね。
ありがとうございます。